# Sort digits in Python

Tags: python, sorting

> Given an integer, sort the digits in ascending order and return the
>   new integer.
>
> - Ignore leading zeros.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - Input: num {Integer}
> - Output: {Integer}
>
> Constraints:
>
> - Do not convert the integer into a string or other data type.
> - Time: O(N) where N is the number of digits.
> - Space: O(1)
>
> Examples:
>
> - 8970 --> 789
> - 32445 --> 23445
> - 10101 --> 111

My code (as follows) works similar to the counting sort:

```
def sort_digits(n):
    digit_counts = {}
    result = 0

    while n > 0:
        digit = n % 10
        digit_counts[digit] = digit_counts.get(digit, 0) + 1
        n /= 10

    power = 0
    for i in range(10, -1, -1):
        if i in digit_counts:
            while digit_counts[i] >= 1:
                result +=  i * (10 ** (power))
                power += 1
                digit_counts[i] -= 1

    return result
```

Comment: Without qualification, the constraint `Do not convert the integer into a string or other data type.` doesn't make much sense. For example, in your solution, you indirectly encode `n` as the dict `digit_counts`, does that count as conversion? I suspect it means "direct" conversion, but that's still a bit silly; more realistic is just `return the value as an int`.

Comment: Suggest specifying this is Python 2... the implementation breaks in Python 3 because `/=` is not a floor divide.

Answer (score 5):

#### 1) Use collections.Counter

`from collections import Counter`. Counter is a subclass of `dict` that helps keep tallies. This way, you don't need `.get(digit, 0)` or `if i in digit_counts`, making your code look a bit cleaner.

#### 2) Iterate in increasing order

Right now, you need a `power` variable to track which position to place the next digit in. If you iterated in the opposite direction (i.e. `range(10)`), you could do `result *= 10` in each loop.

#### 3) Use a `for` loop instead of `while`

Whenever you are iterating and incrementing/decrementing, you have the opportunity to use a for loop. In this case, for `while digit_counts[i] >= 1` you don't care about the number of iterations, so you can use the `_` as a "throwaway variable".

#### 4) Code localization

Move `result = 0` down so that it's just above where it starts being used. Code localization improves readability - depending on your source, the human brain can only remember 4-7 things at once. The fewer variables your reader has to track, the better.

## Final Result

```
from collections import Counter

def sort_digits(n):
  digit_counts = Counter()

  while n > 0:
    digit_counts[n % 10] += 1
    n /= 10

  result = 0
  for i in range(10):
    for _ in range(digit_counts[i]):
      result = 10 * result + i

  return result
```

Comment: To make the integer division clear, it would be better to write `n //= 10` even in Python 2 . And that way your proposed solution will work in Python 3 too.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use a simple list to count digits

Instead of a dictionary, you can simply use a list, for example:

```
digit_counts = [0] * 10

while n > 0:
    digit_counts[n % 10] += 1
    n //= 10
```

No need for other libraries.

#### doctests

Doctests are an easy way to verify your solution produces the expected output to different inputs. For example:

```
def sort_digits(n):
    """
    >>> sort_digits(8970)
    789

    >>> sort_digits(32445)
    23445

    >>> sort_digits(10101)
    111

    """
    # ... the implementation
```

And then run the script with `python -mdoctest script.py`.